# How to use ko.validation.group function

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

I am trying to use knockout.validation plugin. I created an exampleViewModel :

```
function exampleViewModel() {
   this.P1 = ko.observable().extend({ required : true });
   this.P2 = ko.observable().extend({ required : true });
   this.P3 = ko.observable().extend({ required : true });
   this.P4 = ko.observable().extend({ required : true });

   this.errors = ko.validation.group(this);
}
```

In the above view model i created a validation group named errors for the current object. Now if any validation rule fails on any 1 property out of 4 than this errors property contains an error message.

`My question is` , if i want to create a validation group of only 3 properties `(P1, P2, P3)` out of 4 than how can i do this ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This worked well for me.  Rather than grouping on `this`, create a proxy object that holds the properties you want validated.

```
this.errors = ko.validation.group({
    P1: this.P1,
    P2: this.P2,
    P3: this.P3
});
```

If you do this, consider using `validatedObservable` instead of `group`.  Not only do you get the errors, but you can collectively check if all the properties are valid using the `isValid` property.

```
this.validationModel = ko.validatedObservable({
    P1: this.P1,
    P2: this.P2,
    P3: this.P3
});

// is the validationModel valid?
this.validationModel.isValid();
// what are the error messages?
this.validationModel.errors();
```

Comment: Used this approach to debug Durandal Observable Plugin validation issue. `this.errors = ko.validation.group({ P1: observable(this, 'P1') });` I believe it should have detected the getter/setters and reacted accordingly, but this at least proved the validation works.

Answer (score 14):

As described in the [documentation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validating-Only-Specific-Observables) the right way to validate only specific observables is:

```
this.errors = ko.validation.group([this.P1, this.P2, this.P3]);
```

Comment: From the documentation: 
>"Notice also that the first parameter does not need to be an array. If you have only a single object, you can pass it in as a bare object, without wrapping it in an array."

Comment: tks for the documentation link!